# lodash cloneDeep remove proxy from object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, es6-proxy

When I deep clone proxy object then it returns a normal object without proxy. but i want proxy object when i deep clone object.

EX:

```
class Abc {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 4;
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, name) {
        return target[name];
      },
    });
  }
}

class Xyz {
  constructor() {
    this.x = new Abc();
    this.y = _.cloneDeep(this.x);
  }
}

var proxyObject = new Xyz().x;
var normalObject = new Xyz().y;
console.log(proxyObject); // Type Proxy
console.log(normalObject); // Type Object
```

Is there any way to clone deep object like original object behavior like this.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any simple (straightforward) solution to this problem.

One way to achieve this functionality is to modify your `Abc` constructor to include the original object itself (not the proxy) in a property (let's say `orig`).

Then you can define your own copy method. When you invoke this method on a proxy object, it fetches the non-proxy object stored in `orig` property, performs lodash's `cloneDeep` and returns new proxy object created from this cloned object.

```js
class Abc {
  constructor(orig = this) {
    this.orig = orig;
    this.a = 4;
    this.arr = [1, 2];
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, name) {
        return target[name];
      },
    });
  }

  copy() {
    const cloned = _.cloneDeep(this.orig);
    return new Proxy(cloned, {
      get(target, name) {
        return target[name];
      }
    });
  }
}

class Xyz {
  constructor() {
    this.x = new Abc();
    this.y = this.x.copy();
  }
}

var proxyObject = new Xyz().x;
var normalObject = new Xyz().y;

console.log(proxyObject); 
console.log(normalObject);

proxyObject.arr.push(3);

console.log(proxyObject.arr);
console.log(normalObject.arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Now both the `proxyObject` and `normalObject` are proxies and we can also see that the proxy object was indeed copied because after running `proxyObject.arr.push(3)` the `normalObject`'s arr stays unchanged.